# Is there a way to wget a private github repo?

Tags: bash, github, confluence

Example:

I'm trying to do something similar to this but unfortunately I haven't been able to get this to work on private repos https://github.com/paul-hammant/pull-request-scraper

I'd like to grab from GitHubs Pull Request  + Commits to essentially make a changelog then upload that into Confluence

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys

Comment: @chicks how exactly do deploy keys help in the above scenario?

Comment: They would give you access to private repos without creating fake user accounts.